# How to use apply() to find a maximum and minimum of a column in a data.frame in R

Tags: r

After searching for a little while, I cannot seem to find something that gives me the answer I am looking for, so if it exists already, feel free to direct me to it.

The question I have is how to use the apply function to return the range(specifically the maximum and the minimum points of a column of a dataframe.)
Example:

```
v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
v2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
v3 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
vdf <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
colnames(vdf) <- c("ID", "Age", "Position")
z <- apply(vdf$Age, 2, range)
```

It gives me this error

```
Error in apply(vdf$Age, 2, range) : 
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

This clearly means I'm not using the apply function right, and the things I'm reading aren't making a whole lot of sense to me. Expected output(instead of the error code) would be

```
[1] 1 5
```

Comment: Just do `range(vdf$Age)`. If you insist on using `apply`, do `apply(vdf[c("Age")], 2, range)`

Comment: Using apply was a requirement of the assignment unfortunately. Would love to have used range though, as I knew that was much easier. Thank you though.

Comment: That's not really what `apply` is for. It's designed for applying a function to dimension(s) of a matrix or array, e.g. `apply(matrix(1:6, 2), 1, median)`. Applied to vectors without a dimension attribute (what makes matrix a matrix), `apply` doesn't know what to do and gives you that error. Applied to a data frame, it will coerce it to a matrix, which can only hold one type, which in your case would turn everything to characters.

Comment: You could do something like `apply(vdf[-1], 2, range)`, but a more robust approach would be something like `aggregate(values ~ ind, data = stack(vdf[-1]), FUN = function(x){c(min = min(x), max = max(x))})`